# How do I apply a condition to change the values of a list of variables? - Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to allow for the values of these pre-defined variables to change based on the input of a user.

I've recently come across the map() function, and I tried using that, though I'm not sure if I used that properly.

In this code, I attempted to decrease the percentages of a list of numbers, and then output those modified numbers, based on the user input.

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3 

list = [a, b, c]

i = 0

def percentage(n):
    while i < 7: 
        n= n*20/100 
i+=1

sample = input("Enter a string: ")

if sample == "Fox":
    map(percentage, list)


cat1 = f"The fox ran at a speed of {a}."
cat2 = f"The shark swam at a speed of {b}."
cat3 = f"The bird flew at a speed of {c}."

print(cat1, cat2, cat3)
print(list)
```

This is the output:

```
Enter a string: Fox 
The fox ran at a speed of 1. The shark swam at a speed of 2. The bird flew at a speed 
of 3. 
[1, 2, 3]
```

What I did didn't change the values. Have I done anything wrong? If not, how can I go about achieving what I want to achieve here?

Comment: 1) Is `i+=1` suppose to be within the while loop of function percentage?, 2) You didn't assign the result of map to anything (thus, the result of map is lost), 3) you shouldn't use builtin function names as variables (i.e. `list` is discouraged as a variable name).

Comment: In this Code the `i+=1` is not in the loop. Also you should probably put the `i=0` into the function. `map` returns the new object and isn't changing the parameters given. So you have to do something like `mapped_list = map(percentages, my_list)`. Also please don't overwrite buildin objects like `list` and call your variable in an other way.

Answer (score 2):

A few mistakes, fixed below with comments to help you understand what's wrong.

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3 

# Do not use buildins as variable names. Renamed to mylist
mylist = [a, b, c]



def percentage(n):
    i = 0  # i shouldnt be a global variable, so move it here.
    while i < 7: 
        n= n*20/100 
        i+=1 # keep iterating in loop, or you will loop forever
    return n # function needs to return value, without it you would get [None,None,None]

sample = input("Enter a string: ")

if sample == "Fox":
    # Map does not change list "in place", it returns map.
    # You need to transform it to list and assign it to "mylist"
    mylist = list(map(percentage, mylist)) 


cat1 = f"The fox ran at a speed of {a}."
cat2 = f"The shark swam at a speed of {b}."
cat3 = f"The bird flew at a speed of {c}."

print(cat1, cat2, cat3)
print(mylist)
```

Output

```
Enter a string: Fox
The fox ran at a speed of 1. The shark swam at a speed of 2. The bird flew at a speed of 3.
[1.28e-05, 2.56e-05, 3.84e-05]
```

Comment: Perfect answer, addresses all the problems in the question code.

Answer (score 1):

You should rename your list to anything but `list` as it's a built-in type and it's bad practice to name your variables after built-in types (e.g. `int`, `float`, `str`, `list`, etc.)

E.g., rename your list `speeds_lst` instead and reference `speeds_lst` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

the `map` function does not modify to `input list` instead it returns a `map` object to get the desired result you need to do this:

```
new_list=list(map(percentage, old_list))
```

Comment: The builtin function `list` is lost to the poster since it was assigned as a variable name i.e. `list = [a, b, c]`

Comment: agree i will modify my answer thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. Fix `percentage` function, it does not return any value, so `map` is not using it, so make it look like this:

```
def percentage(n):
    i = 0
    while i < 7:
        n = n * 20 / 100
        i += 1
    return n
```

2. `map` will return a result, you have to assign it to your, and as @Adam suggested, you ought to rename your list, so your condition will look like

```
if sample == "Fox":
    speeds_lst = list(map(percentage, speeds_lst))
```

3. fix the printing to use `speeds_lst[]` instead of a, b or c

```
cat1 = f"The fox ran at a speed of {speeds_lst[0]}."
cat2 = f"The shark swam at a speed of {speeds_lst[1]}."
cat3 = f"The bird flew at a speed of {speeds_lst[2]}."
```

The final snippet

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

speeds_lst = [a, b, c]

def percentage(n):
    i = 0
    while i < 7:
        n = n * 20 / 100
        i += 1
    return n

sample = input("Enter a string: ")

if sample == "Fox":
    speeds_lst = list(map(percentage, speeds_lst))

cat1 = f"The fox ran at a speed of {speeds_lst[0]}."
cat2 = f"The shark swam at a speed of {speeds_lst[1]}."
cat3 = f"The bird flew at a speed of {speeds_lst[2]}."

print(cat1, cat2, cat3)
print(speeds_lst)
```